# Nuxt 3 How to add Cache Control to generated static files

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am creating SSR project with Nuxt 3.
I am thinking to add `Cache-Control` Header to generated static files in `.output/_nuxt` directory.

I tried below code  `server/middleware/cache-control.ts`

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  let res = event.res
  const year = 31536000
  const tenmin = 600
  const url = event.req.url
  const maxage = url.match(/(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|svg|mjs)/) ? year : tenmin
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', `max-age=${maxage} s-maxage=${maxage}`);
})
```

But, it does not work.

[image]

How to add `Cache-Control` to the generated static files?

Comment: Files don't respond to request. Server has to set headers.

Comment: `console.log` tells that network does not go through Nuxt3 server. I think I need to configure Vite server.

Comment: I add below code to `nuxt.config.js`. But still does not wok...

``` js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    server: {
      headers: {
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=11111, s-maxage=11111"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Nuxt 3 uses Nitro server by default. Where do you host your application ? Universal app can get just once files from server and then get others from other static files host. If it does like that, you have to set headers in both server and host server.

Comment: I was miss understanding what default server is... I have to add some settings to Nitro. I am currently testing with in Docker. I do not need to set host server headers for now.

Comment: It's experimental but you could try the new Route Rules:
https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/concepts/rendering#route-rules

but instead if you host you App on Vercel you can do it in the vercel.config file: https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-configure-the-cache-control-response-header-in-vercel-projects

I guess Netlify has something similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figure out by myself. Adding bellow code to `nuxt.config.js` will append cache-control to your static files. Thank you for your support!

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  nitro: {
    routeRules: {
      "/img/**": { headers: { 'cache-control': `public,max-age=${year},s-maxage=${year}` } },
      "/_nuxt/**": { headers: { 'cache-control': `public,max-age=${year},s-maxage=${year}` } },
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: For whom are struggling in dev mode nuxt: I was able to check cache header when I build nuxt using:

npm run build
export NUXT_API_HOST='[YOUR SERVER URL]'
export PORT='8080'
node .output/server/index.mjs

Answer (score 3):

For Nuxt3 I have used this as server middleware `server/middleware/cache-control.js`

```
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
    const url = event.node.req.url;
    const maxage = url.match(/(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|svg|css|js|mjs)/)
      ? 60 * 60 * 12 * 30
      : 60 * 60;
    appendHeader(
      event,
      "Cache-Control",
      `max-age=${maxage} s-maxage=${maxage}`
    );
  } else {
    appendHeader(event, "Cache-Control", `max-age=${60} s-maxage=${60}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the h3 function:

```
appendHeader(res, name, value)
```

Nuxt 3 works based on: https://github.com/unjs/h3

Answer (score 0):

**Nuxt 3**

Using Nuxt 3 hook in plugins path `plugins/cache.server.ts` :

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.hook('app:rendered', ctx => {
        ctx.ssrContext?.event.node.res.setHeader('cache-control', `max-age=${60*60*24*365}`)
    })
})
```

Using Nitro hook in server path `server/plugins/cache.ts` :

```js
import { RenderResponse } from "nitropack"

export default defineNitroPlugin((nitroApp) => {
    nitroApp.hooks.hook('render:response', (res: RenderResponse) => {
        res.headers['cache-control'] = `max-age=${60*60*24*365}`
    })
})
```