# Nuxt 3 - how to add Cache-Control to static files?

Tags: nuxt.js

In Nuxt3, how can I add the Cache-Control header to automatically generated files?

In nuxt 2, it was done by adding these lines to `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
render: {
    static: {
      maxAge: '1y'
    }
  }
```

What is the equivalent in Nuxt 3?

*I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72977133/nuxt-3-how-to-add-cache-control-to-generated-static-files) which shares the same title but wasn't answered*

Answer (score 2):

You can try it by add `server/middleware/cache-control.ts` file.

```
export default defineEventHandler(event => {
  const res = event.node.res;
  const year = 31536000;
  const hour = 60 * 60;
  const url = event.node.req.url;
  if (url) {
    const maxage = url.match(/(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|svg|mjs)/) ? year : hour;
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', `max-age=${maxage} s-maxage=${maxage}`);
  }
});
```

Referenced from [here](https://paulund.co.uk/add-cache-control-to-nuxt3).

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem, this helps me

```
vite: {
    server: {
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=31536000'
        }
    }
}
```

source: https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-headers

Comment: this works locally, but is there a reason why it's not working on production?

Comment: @OlieCape vite only runs locally, actually that's not the right answer

Answer (score 0):

It's experimental but you could try the new Route Rules:
https://nitro.unjs.io/config#routerules

but instead if you host you App on Vercel you can do it in the vercel.config file: https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-configure-the-cache-control-response-header-in-vercel-projects

I guess Netlify has something similar.