# Add headers in a route middleware in Nux 3

Tags: vuejs3, http-headers, middleware, nuxt3, response-headers

I'm migrating a Nuxt 2 to Nuxt 3 application and I need to add an header to the responses that arrive to a specific page.
While I'm aware on how to add named route middleware in Vue components, I'm not finding the way of editing the headers using the 'from' and 'to' parameters.

Moreover, I've read that this can be done with server middleware (inside server folder) but at the same time, all the server middleware is applied to all the requests, which is not the desired behavior here.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thank you very much,

Comment: What exactly is the use case? What are the headers used for?

Comment: Regarding server middleware - although it will run before each server route, you can still read the request URL and only execute your code in valid cases. The request data should be in `event.node.req` IIRC

Comment: thank you, the use case is to add cache-control headers to each http request that is comming

Comment: I found the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72977133/nuxt-3-how-to-add-cache-control-to-generated-static-files

Comment: How could I do this in route middleware ? (adding headers I mean)
because now I need to add an header with the locale, which can't be obtained in the nuxt.config file